# What is the best way to let user change proportions?

Tags: flutter

I would like to find the best widget(s) to change proportions.

Let's say I have 2 to 10 parts that sum up to 100%. I would like to create a widget where the user can change those parts as they want and they have to sum up to 100% at the end.

For example: There is a container with 100ml of volume. The user has 3 different ingredients and can choose how much ml of each ingredient is in the container.

Do widgets like that exist and if not, what would be the best approach to deal with it (Sliders?)?

Comment: no, you have to write you own function for this, I would recommend sliders for the input but you can choose whatever you want

Comment: enclose CustomPainter with a Gesture detector, draw the different colored rect according to drag, got the idea?

Comment: thank you, I need to look at Custompainter. Each ingredient should be a rectangle enclosed in a Gesturedetector?